# If I build my current .NET projects with Visual Studio 2014 using Roslyn, will I experience build performance improvement?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, roslyn

I've read the Visual Studio 2014 CTP annoucement and it says it uses Roslyn by default: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp-now-available.aspx

So I'm assuming that my current .NET projects (ASP.NET MVC projects, to be precise) will be compiled using Roslyn by default.

The question is: Will my projects build faster, at least probably? I'm specially interested in incremental compilation, like, if I change just a comma, I'd really like Roslyn to be smarter than the current MSBuild and build the project faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

Mostly it depends on solution size and your machine.  The Roslyn compilers will cache metadata loads between projects, and will compile methods in parallel.  These two things generally mean you will get better performance on multi-project solutions, particularly on multi-core machines.

For your specific question, it is unlikely that you will notice a difference in the small change to a project with no dependencies case.